# How to customize or change Default crosswalk decompress dialogue?

Tags: javascript, android, crosswalk-runtime, crosswalk, crosswalk-project

I am working on a project which uses crosswalk light, and I just want to change the test or customize the loading UI showing when the crosswalk decompresses the runtime environment.[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem?